# Angular-material not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lvdl4XpReQr6AzsuOQhP?p=preview

While using angular-material getting following error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24forceReflowProvid…eQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

Routing.JS :

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('angularMaterial', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial']);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/main", {
                templateUrl: 'main.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/main" });

    });
}());
```

Index.html : Shell for displaying html pages based on routing

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularMaterial">

  <head>
    <title>Angular Material Fundamentals</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link data-require="angular-material@*" data-semver="1.1.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular-material@*" data-semver="1.1.0" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-aria@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-messages@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="routing.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-cloak="">
    <header>
      <h1>
        Angular Material Fundamentals </h1>
    </header>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Main.html :

```
<div>

    <md-content flex layout-padding>
        {{message}}
    </md-content>


</div>
```

MainController.js :

```
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Angular Material is a UI component library for Angular JS developers. Angular Material components helps in constructing attractive, consistent, and functional web pages and web apps while adhering to modern web design principles like browser portability, device independence, and graceful degradation. It helps in creating faster, beautiful, and responsive websites. It is inspired from Google Material Design.";

}


MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('angularMaterial').controller('MainController', MainController);
```

Please help.....Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular material have a dependency on angular so you need to add **angular.js** first and then **angular-material.min.js** resource file.

The order of adding script resource should be

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-material@*" data-semver="1.1.0" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/D8KNdE4phpxwCf6N5s4x?p=preview